# Best way to redirect domain.com/en to domain.com

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I'm launching a new version of a website and I'd like to remove english language paths from the new URLs - since english is the default language of the site.

Basically I want domain.com instead of domain.com/en as the base of all english URLs. I'm assuming that I have to rewrite that part of the domain in order to update all the URLs that include that path. Otherwise my next guess is that I should simply 301 redirect all URLs on the site to the new URLs? Assuming the first method is correct, should this work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com/en
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com$1 [L,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You want this instead:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =domain.com
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

To go in a `.htaccess` file since your question is tagged that. Would need changing to go in main config unless in a `<Directory>` block.

You probably don't need the line checking the host, unless this is on a site serving multiple domains and should only apply to one of them, and also it will stop the rule working for www.domain.com, which may or may not be an issue for you. Just mentioning it.